# Derivative of a quotient

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find

$$y = \frac{x^2 + 4x + 3}{ \sqrt{x}}$$

I am reviewing this so I am suppose to do it without the quotient rule, just using what I know about 16 years of algebra and the power rule, difference rule and such. I cannot get it, or anything close to the answer.

I attempted to find the answer using the quotient rule and it was still wrong, I am not sure why I am following the rules and this does not work. There is probably some trick or some exception at play here that I am not familiar with.

Comment: Can you simplify the equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:$$y = \frac{x^2 + 4x + 3}{ \sqrt{x}}=x^{3/2}+4x^{1/2}+3x^{-1/2}$$

and we know for all $r\in R$: $$\frac{d}{dx}x^r=rx^{r-1}$$

Comment: But why is this the trick to make it work? I couldn't do it without doing this.

Comment: @Jordan If you wanted to do it withou this then I think you need the quotient rule.And by the way this is not a trick.This is quite standard.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to log both sides. On RHS you get 
$$
\log (x^2 +4x+3)-\frac{1}{2}\log x
$$
The derivative of this is 
$$
\frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+3}-\frac{1}{2x}
$$
Hence the derivative of your function is 
$$
f'(x)=f(x)\bigg(\frac{2x+4}{x^2+4x+3}-\frac{1}{2x}\bigg)
$$

Comment: Why in the world would you do this? You just made the problem thousands times more complex. I have no clue how to get the derivative of a log, I don't even know how to use logs. It just looks like you are showing off.

Comment: @Jordan: it's a useful technique, e.g. if you need to take derivative of functions of the form $g(x)^{h(x)}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative

Comment: I don't think it is showing off. +1. It's not useful in this particular computation of the derivative I think, but definitely has its uses.

Comment: Why complicate an intro problem? I like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Quotient Law should work. There is no trick that I see.

Typically you would use Product Rule if you wanted to avoid Quotient Law, since it is easy to change a quotient into a product.

Recall: Given $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, $h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$

I will evaluate the derivative without Quotient Law as requested.

$h(x) = \frac{x^2 + 4x + 3}{ \sqrt{x}}=x^{(2-1/2)}+4x^{(1-1/2)}+3x^{(0-1/2)}=x^{3/2}+4x^{1/2}+3x^{-1/2}$

$h'(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^{1/2}+2x^{-1/2}+\frac{-3}{2}x^{-3/2}$ (Using the Power Rule)

Just in case you don't remember the Power Rules: $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1},n\neq0.$